# Unique filtered index and surprising estimation

Tags: sql-server, execution-plan

When I view the estimated execution plan for this query...

```
SELECT *
FROM tabela2  x
     LEFT JOIN dbo.tabela1 t with (nolock) on t.Kod = x.Kod
```

... the **Estimated Number of Rows** property for `[table1]` shows **10**. Why is this? In the schema (copied below) I have a unique index `AKF_tabela1_Kod`. Shouldn't this unique index force the row estimation to be **1**?

### Estimated Execution Plan

[image: query plan]

### Create Database, Tables and Index

```
-- create database 
USE [master]
GO
DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS my_test;
CREATE DATABASE my_test;
GO
ALTER DATABASE my_test SET AUTO_CREATE_STATISTICS OFF;
ALTER AUTHORIZATION ON DATABASE ::my_test TO sa;
USE my_test
GO

-- create dbo.tabela1

CREATE TABLE dbo.[tabela1] 
    (
    [Id] int NOT NULL identity(1,1),
    [kol1] varchar(20) NOT NULL,
    [Kod] int NULL,  
    CONSTRAINT [PK_tabela1] PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED([id] ASC) WITH (ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON),
    CONSTRAINT [BK_tabela1] UNIQUE CLUSTERED([Kol1] ASC) WITH (ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON),
    );
GO

-- create Index 

CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [AKF_tabela1_Kod] 
    ON dbo.[tabela1]([Kod] ASC) 
    INCLUDE ([id],[kol1]) 
    WHERE ([Kod] IS NOT NULL) 
    WITH (ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, MAXDOP = 0);
GO

-- create dbo.tabela2

IF  OBJECT_ID('dbo.tabela2') IS NULL
  CREATE TABLE tabela2 (Kod int NOT NULL)
GO
```

### Insert Data into Table

```
-- create data in tabela1
declare @i int=1
    while @i<=100
    begin
      INSERT tabela1 (kol1, kod)
      values (@i, cast(@i+100 as varchar))
      set @i += 1;
    end;
GO

UPDATE STATISTICS tabela1 WITH FULLSCAN;
```

*Here the [Execution plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=r1oPgB6y4)*

Comment: Why is there an exclamation mark in your Index Seek?

Comment: I've checked it on my server and on [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=4daa0be2a43a8115d3375ec6d5b9bfdb) and the ENR = 1. [The Plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=B1mfBQpk4)

Comment: Because the automatic statistics creation option has been disabled on the database. If there is a dedicated index filtered (seek) on a column , why do I need the statistics not filtered on the entire column? Rhetorical is the question :). The question is, why SQL Server does not correctly estimate the number of rows based on a unique filtered index? Is this a paradox that uses a unique index and estimates a value greater than 1?

Comment: It might be easier for people to answer if you [share the execution plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/).

Comment: Here you are :) : https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=r1oPgB6y4

Comment: Execute 
Create statistics ST_Tablea1_Kod on dbo.tabela1(kod) and  recompile your query to get the right 1 estimated row seek

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using? Do you have any specific flags configured for this instance?

Answer (score 4):

> the Estimated Number of Rows property for [table1] shows 10. Why is
>   this? In the schema (copied below) I have a unique index
>   AKF_tabela1_Kod. Shouldn't this unique index force the row estimation
>   to be 1?

The statistics are created when creating the unique index, but as a result of the unique index being filtered, the statistics are also filtered.
(where kod is not null).

As a result, the query as it is cannot use these statistics.

**Why?**

The Index can be used, but the statistics are not a match for the query.

Even if you do a select on kod:

```
 select kod from dbo.tabela1 t 
     where kod is not null  option(recompile)
```

The statistics are still no match:
[image]

If you do a select of the id however:

```
 select id from dbo.tabela1 t 
 where kod is not null  option(recompile)
```

There is a match:

[image]

This seems to be buggy with auto create stats:

```
ALTER DATABASE my_test SET AUTO_CREATE_STATISTICS ON;

 select kod from dbo.tabela1 t 
 where kod is not null  option(recompile)
```

This does not create stats for some reason, but is still able to do the correct estimation.
[image]

No new stats:

[image]

Re running this:

```
 ALTER DATABASE my_test SET AUTO_CREATE_STATISTICS OFF;

 select kod from dbo.tabela1 t 
 where kod is not null  option(recompile)
```

Gives the same warning:
[image]

This seems to be an issue with auto create statistics being off, even though no stats are created.

I am not sure, but an estimate of 10 might be a 'default' value to use, like when using a table variable.

**Workarounds:**

## 1

If you create the next index, the result will be 1 estimated rows

```
CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [AKF_tabela1_Kod2] 
    ON dbo.[tabela1]([Kod] ASC) 
    INCLUDE ([id]) 
    WITH (ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, MAXDOP = 0);
GO
```

## 2

Another route you could take is creating your own statistics:

```
 create statistics ST_Tablea1_Kod on dbo.tabela1(kod)
```

**Retry the query (with a new execution plan):**

```
SELECT *
FROM tabela2  x
     LEFT JOIN dbo.tabela1 t with (nolock) on  t.Kod = x.Kod option(recompile)
```

[image]
[image]

## 3

Or ofcourse, enable auto create statistics and rerun the query:

```
ALTER DATABASE my_test SET AUTO_CREATE_STATISTICS ON;
```

**Update:**

The below queries give a stat missing on the first execution, but not on the other two. A statistic was created by auto create stats.

```
     SELECT *
FROM tabela2  x
     LEFT JOIN dbo.tabela1 t with (nolock) on t.Kod = x.Kod option(recompile)
      ALTER DATABASE my_test SET AUTO_CREATE_STATISTICS ON;
         SELECT *
FROM tabela2  x
     LEFT JOIN dbo.tabela1 t with (nolock) on t.Kod = x.Kod option(recompile)
           ALTER DATABASE my_test SET AUTO_CREATE_STATISTICS OFF;

             SELECT *
FROM tabela2  x
     LEFT JOIN dbo.tabela1 t with (nolock) on t.Kod = x.Kod option(recompile)
```

[image]

**Dropping the stats and retrying with a select:**

```
     drop statistics  dbo.tabela1.[_WA_Sys_00000003_0EA330E9]

 select kod from dbo.tabela1 t 
 where kod is not null  option(recompile)

     ALTER DATABASE my_test SET AUTO_CREATE_STATISTICS ON;

 select kod from dbo.tabela1 t 
 where kod is not null  option(recompile)

     ALTER DATABASE my_test SET AUTO_CREATE_STATISTICS OFF;

 select kod from dbo.tabela1 t 
 where kod is not null  option(recompile)
```

Does not generate stats, and gives the same missing index hints on the first and third execution:

[image]

I thought that this maybe was because of the optimization level being trivial. But this was not the case.

```
StatementOptmLevel="TRIVIAL"
```

**Non trivial optimization level:**

```
 select kod from dbo.tabela1 t 
 where kod is not null 
 group by kod  option(recompile)

     ALTER DATABASE my_test SET AUTO_CREATE_STATISTICS ON;

 select kod from dbo.tabela1 t 
 where kod is not null     group by kod   option(recompile)

     ALTER DATABASE my_test SET AUTO_CREATE_STATISTICS OFF;

 select kod from dbo.tabela1 t 
 where kod is not null    group by kod   option(recompile)
```

Result:
[image]

Query #2 with automatic stat creation:
[image]
(I added 100 rows for a total of 200)

Query #3 , after putting automatic stat creation off again:
[image]
(180 estimated rows)

As a conclusion, this should have something to do with automatic stat creation being disabled.
My guess is on some sort of temporary stats or the way the plan is created. 
I checked if i could find any 'temp'stats that are created at runtime,
but i did not find anything.
    (select * from sys.stats where is_temporary = 1)